# Getting UIButton to stay highlighted after tap

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm trying to replicate the scroll selector at the bottom of the emoji keyboard, where you can select the category by tapping on the appropriate icon and it will also show you in which category you are if you scroll. However, I'm having trouble getting the selected button to appear highlighted for some reason. I can get the scroll to work fine, but when I click on the icon it won't stay highlighted. Is this to do with some property of the touchUpInside trigger and the highlighted property?

**My Code**

```
var categoryButtons = [UIButton]()
var categoryDistances = [CGFloat]()

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    var curIndex = -1

    for d in categoryDistances {

        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x + 5 >= d) {
            curIndex += 1
        }
    }

    for b in categoryButtons {
        b.isHighlighted = false
    }

    if (curIndex == -1) {
        curIndex = 0
    }

    categoryButtons[curIndex].isHighlighted = true

}

func shortcutSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {

    snapSelector.contentOffset.x = categoryDistances[categoryButtons.index(of: sender)!]

    for b in categoryButtons {
        b.isHighlighted = false
    }

    sender.isHighlighted = true

}
```

Comment: Use isSelected to keep the selected state instead of highlighted state will be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work the way I wanted by applying a tint color instead of using the `isHighlighted` or `isSelected` properties:

```
let tintedImg = origImg?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
let shortcut = UIButton()
shortcut.setBackgroundImage(tintedImg, for: .normal)
shortcut.tintColor = UIColor.gray
```